# Custom field - Object could be converted to string

Tags: plugins

I have a very simple custom field/widget/formatter set.

**YoutubeLink.php (custom field):**

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\ad_general\Plugin\FIeld\FieldType;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;
/**
 * Defines the 'boolean' entity field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "youtube",
 *   label = @Translation("Youtube link"),
 *   description = @Translation("Youtube link field."),
 *   default_widget = "youtube_default",
 *   default_formatter = "youtube_default",
 * )
 */
class YoutubeLink extends FieldItemBase {

  public function isEmpty() {
    $value = $this->get('value')->getValue();
    return $value === NULL || $value === '';
  }

  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties['value'] = DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('Youtube link'));
    return $properties;
  }

  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return [
      'columns' => [
        'value' => [
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 255,
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

**YoutubeLinkWidget.php (custom widget):**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ad_general\Plugin\FIeld\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'text_textarea' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "youtube_default",
 *   label = @Translation("Youtube default"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "youtube"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class YoutubeLinkWidget extends WidgetBase {

  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $elements = [];

    $elements['value'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Enter Youtube video link.',
    ];

    return $elements;
  }
}
```

**YoutubeLinkFormatter.php (custom formatter):**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ad_general\Plugin\FIeld\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase;

/**
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "youtube_default",
 *   label = @Translation("Youtube link"),
 *   description = @Translation("Display a link to the video."),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "youtube"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class YoutubeLinkFormatter extends FormatterBase {

  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = [];
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $elements[$delta] = [
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => $item,
      ];
    }

    return $elements;
  }
}
```

I added this field to a content type. Whenever I want to add new content of this type, I now get the following error:

> Youtube link The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try
>   again later. Recoverable fatal error: Object of class
>   Drupal\ad_general\Plugin\FIeld\FieldType\YoutubeLink could not be
>   converted to string in Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filter() (line 67
>   of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Xss.php).
>   Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filter(Object, Array) (Line: 753)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->ensureMarkupIsSafe(Array) (Line: 384)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 490)
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array,
>   'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 128)
>   __TwigTemplate_5b03bca200df2d5ba1ca47d2e222b86347639abbdcd0d8d587ebad065efba4c8->doDisplay(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 432) Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 403) Twig_Template->display(Array) (Line: 411)
>   Twig_Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
>   twig_render_template('core/themes/classy/templates/field/field.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384) Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('field',
>   Array) (Line: 437) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, )
>   (Line: 195) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 490)
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array,
>   'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 87)
>   __TwigTemplate_427ceffeef7118469d7753956e2b0d458f0c2f44d3b385e4ec36128cfc86801f->block_content(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 215) Twig_Template->displayBlock('content', Array,
>   Array) (Line: 72)
>   __TwigTemplate_427ceffeef7118469d7753956e2b0d458f0c2f44d3b385e4ec36128cfc86801f->doDisplay(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 432) Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 403) Twig_Template->display(Array) (Line: 411)
>   Twig_Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
>   twig_render_template('core/themes/bartik/templates/block.html.twig',
>   Array) (Line: 384) Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('block',
>   Array) (Line: 437) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line:
>   450) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 490)
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array,
>   'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 56)
>   __TwigTemplate_6bc2c2a4be03937decaa4eb1c0d39af747b44d5c7e30912d8db85c3fa5c28de6->doDisplay(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 432) Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 403) Twig_Template->display(Array) (Line: 411)
>   Twig_Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
>   twig_render_template('core/themes/stable/templates/layout/layout--onecol.html.twig',
>   Array) (Line: 384)
>   Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('layout__onecol', Array) (Line:
>   437) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 450)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 450)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 490)
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array,
>   'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 114)
>   __TwigTemplate_4ae59022820823361d314fdb0db03eda142ac3295eb1399a7323e963e3d3bf5a->doDisplay(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 432) Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 403) Twig_Template->display(Array) (Line: 411)
>   Twig_Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
>   twig_render_template('core/themes/bartik/templates/node.html.twig',
>   Array) (Line: 384) Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('node',
>   Array) (Line: 437) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, )
>   (Line: 195) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}()
>   (Line: 582)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object)
>   (Line: 227)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object,
>   Object) (Line: 117)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array,
>   Object, Object) (Line: 90)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object,
>   'kernel.view', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view',
>   Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view',
>   Object) (Line: 156)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line:
>   68) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 57) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 47) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 99)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   78) Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 52)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 23) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   666) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this issue? Thank you very much for any sort of help.

Comment: $item is likely an object and not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `#markup` property of the formatter - `$item` is indeed just an object, so I had to convert it to a string by using the `getString()` method (as an example).